# Matlab GUI windowButtonMotionFcn Slow When No Action Taken

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a MATLAB (r2016a) GUI with a windowButtonMotionFcn callback. Inside the callback is an if-elseif-else block that changes the cursor depending on which axes in the GUI the mouse is over. It runs very quickly when it encounters the cases when it needs to change something, but according to profiler, takes a significant amount of time on the "return" command.

Can anyone offer insight into a way to correct this? It seems to me if it's not executing any more code, it should be running more quickly when it is exiting the function (i.e. not getting hung up on a "return") than when it has more code to execute.

A basic outline of the code is as follows:

```
function mouseMove(handles)

xy = %Get cursor position

if %xy over axes1
    set(gcf,'Pointer','crosshair')
elseif %xy over axes2
    set(gcf,'Pointer','arrow')
else
    return %Here is where MATLAB is spending a lot of time
end

%A lot of additional code for when the cursor is over axes1 or axes2.

end
```

Comment: I have no idea how the profiler works for GUIs, but are you sure that line does't take more time because its run more often i.e. generally xy is not over axes? Are you referring that it takes longer *per call* or in total?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have a return there? Won't this cause the code to exit the mouseMove function before reaching the "additional code for when the cursor is over axes1/axes2?"

Comment: @AnderBiguri That is possible. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to the fact that the [`end` of a  function often appears in the profiler as taking a lot of time](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20424-why-would-an-end-statement-have-execution-time-in-the-profiler). In general, the profiler is good for identifying inefficiencies in your code (functions that are called too many times, etc.) but really isn't well-suited to actually benchmarking code since JIT acceleration isn't enabled. For benchmarking, it's best to use `timeit` or some other function.

That being said, when I implement your same callback, I don't see any performance hit for the `return` statement

[image]

As @Ander pointed out, you should pay attention to the **Calls** column as it's possible that the number of times that `return` is called is simply more than the rest of the callback. The default coloration of a given line is based on the *total time* and not the time per call.

Comment: So it turns out that the time _per call_ was approximately the same for each case. To fix the performance issue I added a check to see when the last time the function was called, and returned if it had been less than 10ms. That made the function run smoothly.